# How to save Infopath form, without using a ribbon nor code?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

Currently I am developing an Infopath form, to be used in Sharepoint form library.

I want the ribbon to be hidden, and user is going to submit form by a button after last field.

After user had submitted the form, data from form is going to be reviewed by another user(from HR), and he will fill a set of hr-specific fields - comments on what is inside. The problem is, that if I do not have a "save" button from the ribbon, the only thing user is capable to do is to submit it once more, creating another file. I do not want users to name files whatever they want, which is why I disabled the ribbon in the first place

How can I create a save button, without using code(Sharepoint configuration does not allow that)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create a very similiar behaviour, by using rules.

I added new hidden field to the form, called `fileName`. I created two submitting options `save` and `submitNew`. The latter is creating filename, the first is loading it from field `fileName`, and can overwrite.

I set submitting options non-standard rules, and then created two rules:

1. If `fileName` is empty, create new file name(for me, it is joined timestamp and city), and add it to `fileName`, and submit it using `submitNew`.
2. If `fileName` is not empty, submit file with name loaded from this field using `save`.

No need for ribbon nor custom code.